# How can I enable tabs by clicking on the button?

Tags: html, jquery, css, tabs, materialize

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tabs').tabs();
  $("#btnContinue").click(function() {
    $("#test2").attr("disabled", "false");
    $("#test3").attr("disabled", "false");
    $("#test4").attr("disabled", "false");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<div class="col s12">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test1">Test 1</a></li>
    <li class="tab col s3 disabled"><a href="#test2">Test 2</a></li>
    <li class="tab col s3 disabled"><a href="#test3">Disabled Tab</a></li>
    <li class="tab col s3 disabled"><a href="#test4">Test 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="test2" class="col s12">Test 2</div>
<div id="test3" class="col s12">Test 3</div>
<div id="test4" class="col s12">Test 4</div>

<div class="modal-content" id="test1">
  <h4>Register</h4>
  <p>A bunch of text</p>
  <form id="signup-form">
    <div class="input-field">
      <input type="email" id="signup-email" required />
      <label for="signup-email">Email address</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field">
      <input type="password" id="signup-password" required />
      <label for="signup-password">Choose password</label>
    </div>
    <button class="btn yellow darken-2 z-depth-0" id="btnContinue">Continue</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

My idea is that I have 4 tabs and 3 of them are disabled(I used materialize css). If the user enter his Email and his Password and then presses the button, all tabs should be enabled(change from disabled to enabled). The problem is that I have no Idea how to implement this(my code is not working). Thanks for any help!

Comment: You are submitting a form to the server which then starts a new page.  Please clarify what you mean more clearly what should be your desired result after the button click

Comment: What for example would be the case where a tab is now reset to "disabled" since all you describe and show in your code is removing the disable on the `<a>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should remove the `class` "`disabled`" not the `attribute` , also remove it from tabs not the div content ,

should be somthing like :

```
$(".tabs .tab").removeClass("disabled");
```

Also I suggest to remove it after form submit , not the button click

```
$("#signup-form").on("submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".tabs .tab").removeClass("disabled");

});
```

Here below a working snippet :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tabs').tabs();
  
  $("#signup-form").on("submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".tabs .tab").removeClass("disabled");
    
    // diable only by id using a href 
    //$(".tabs .tab").has('a[href="#test2"]').removeClass("disabled")
    
    
    // or your can get only get next tab
    // $(".tabs .tab").has('a.active').next().removeClass("disabled");
  })


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<div class="col s12">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test1">Test 1</a></li>
    <li class="tab col s3 disabled"><a href="#test2">Test 2</a></li>
    <li class="tab col s3 disabled"><a href="#test3">Disabled Tab</a></li>
    <li class="tab col s3 disabled"><a href="#test4">Test 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="test2" class="col s12">Test 2</div>
<div id="test3" class="col s12">Test 3</div>
<div id="test4" class="col s12">Test 4</div>

<div class="modal-content" id="test1">
  <h4>Register</h4>
  <p>A bunch of text</p>
  <form id="signup-form">
    <div class="input-field">
      <input type="email" id="signup-email" required />
      <label for="signup-email">Email address</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field">
      <input type="password" id="signup-password" required />
      <label for="signup-password">Choose password</label>
    </div>

    <button class="btn yellow darken-2 z-depth-0" id="btnContinue">Continue</button>
  </form>
</div>
<script>
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for help, do you know how to enable only one tab? for example tab 2.

Comment: yes you can use only the href of that class like : `$(".tabs .tab").has('a[href="#test2"]').removeClass("disabled")`

or simply get each step only next tab and make it active using 
`$(".tabs .tab").has('a.active').next().removeClass("disabled")`
I put the examples in snipet you can uncomment and check them

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tabs').tabs();
  $("#btnContinue").click(function() {
    $(".tab").removeClass("disabled");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<div class="col s12">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test1">Test 1</a></li>
    <li class="tab col s3 disabled"><a href="#test2">Test 2</a></li>
    <li class="tab col s3 disabled"><a href="#test3">Disabled Tab</a></li>
    <li class="tab col s3 disabled"><a href="#test4">Test 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="test2" class="col s12">Test 2</div>
<div id="test3" class="col s12">Test 3</div>
<div id="test4" class="col s12">Test 4</div>

<div class="modal-content" id="test1">
  <h4>Register</h4>
  <p>A bunch of text</p>
  <form id="signup-form">
    <div class="input-field">
      <input type="email" id="signup-email" required />
      <label for="signup-email">Email address</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field">
      <input type="password" id="signup-password" required />
      <label for="signup-password">Choose password</label>
    </div>
    <button class="btn yellow darken-2 z-depth-0" id="btnContinue" type="button">Continue</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: added attribute `type="button"` to the button to prevent form submit ;)